# Can we blindly trust Django ERROR "you may need to add xxx to ALLOWED_HOSTS"?

Tags: django, security

Regularly I receive from my server these kind of errors:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '139.162.113.11'. You may need to add '139.162.113.11' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

The problem is that my server works fine and I don't know where do these IP addresses are coming from.

If I try to localize the one in example, it appears to be in Tokyo, which is weird to me, having a server based in France for mainly european customers.

Can't it be a suspicious attempt to the server security? I'm not keen to allow this IP. What is the correct attitude toward this kind of error?

Comment: This is exactly what should happen. If you allow all hosts, your site could be served by someone malicious that could intercept and "poison" all of your site's content.

Comment: `I don't know where do these IP addresses are coming from.` 
Have a [look](https://serverfault.com/a/550003)

Comment: @EnePaul And what do you think about a 192.168.0.1 address which doesn't appear in ifconfig results? Or the reverse IP of my server? Isn't it strange to get this error with these addresses?

Comment: That could be used for an attack too. See https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-a-host-header-attack. See the screenshot on the bottom of the page. They used a "fake" local ip address

Answer (score 0):

You can "trust" that Django is helping prevent your app from running on disallowed hosts!

However- you can't blindly trust that these IPs should be allowed to host your application. They're typically some kind of bot scanning services poking around for vulnerabilities in servers to do nasty things.

Heck- I have a few of these DISALLOWED_HOST warnings in my inbox this morning as I wake up!

There is a logging option `django.security.DisallowedHost` where you can quiet this issue- however I keep it on as a barometer for bot activity.

Comment: Right, it's how I see it, like you said, a barometer for bot activity. But I was uncertain, after one year I receive these errors, I wanted to give it a deeper insight